# How to recover important files from corrupted hard disk that keeps on loading

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, recovery, sata-to-usb

I had dual boot in my hard disk, but one day my system hanged and when i tried to restart it,i ran into grub recovery mode, then later i tried again but i was not able to view any sector list in my harddisk by using the *ls* command in grub recovery terminal, so i took the hard disk out and by using SATA to USB adapter connected it to my other system, Using gparted when i tried to look in my 1TB partitions, It just kept on loading(Image attached). Even in the file explorer i can see 2-3 new folders but on getting inside them it keeps on loading. I am not able to test any disk checking/recovery option because on using those softwares with hdd it just keeps on loading finding the disk, what should i do ??

[image: gparted on connecting the external hdd]

Comment: The sdb drive is not a 1TB drive, it's likely a 16GB flash drive. You may or may not find the drive you want in the dropdown menu. In any case showing this "image" is irrelevant.

Comment: yes actually its was flash drive, what happened was before plugging in the hdd i plugged the flash drive to see if gparted can detect it, but even after disconnecting the results persisted. Now i conncected the hdd first and then checked gparted. I have updated the question. Thanks